# Array of sprite animation libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to create a game for a university project. In the main menu, i animated a character with this:

```
spidey = new Texture("spidey.png");
TextureRegion[][] tmpFrames = 
TextureRegion.split(spidey,spidey.getWidth()/3,spidey.getHeight()/5);
animationFrames = new TextureRegion[15];
int index = 0;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
        animationFrames[index++] = tmpFrames[i][j];
    }
}
animation = new Animation(0.15f, (Object[]) animationFrames);
```

But if i have an array of character like this:

```
public void characters() {
enemies = new Array<Enemy>();
enemies.add(new Enemy(new Sprite(new Texture("img1.png")), spawn));
enemies.add(new Enemy(new Sprite(new Texture("img2.png")), spawn));
enemies.add(new Enemy(new Sprite(new Texture("img3.png")), spawn));
enemies.add(new Enemy(new Sprite(new Texture("img4.png")), spawn));      
}
```

How can i animate all character?

Comment: Your first example seems to be fine. Why don't you just create the animation for enemies in the same way?

Comment: I just need some advice, because I don't know how to use animation for each element of my array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use an animation for you enemy you don't need to create an Array of enemies, but an `Animation` object for an enemy, just like you did in the first code snippet in you question.

Something like this:

```
public void character() {
  TextureRegion[] enemyAnimationTextures = new TextureRegion[] {new Texture("img1.png"), new Texture("img2.png"), new Texture("img3.png"), new Texture("img4.png")};
  Animation<TextureRegion> animation = new Animation<>(0.15f, enemyAnimationTextures, PlayMode.LOOP); // use PlayMode.NORMAL if you don't want the animation to loop
  enemy = new Enemy(animation);
}
```

Now you enemy needs to be able to draw the animation. Therefore you need to add a draw method that gets the delta time as a parameter (or you get the delta time from `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()`, like in [this tutorial](https://libgdx.com/wiki/graphics/2d/2d-animation) (which is a bit outdated but should still work...):

```
// in you Enemy class
private float animationStateTime = 0f;
private Animation<TextureRegion> animation;
private SpriteBatch spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

public Enemy(Animation<TextureRegion> animation) {
  this.animation = animation;
}

public void draw() {
  animationStateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); // a bit outdated, but working
  
  // get the current frame of the animation for this enemy
  TextureRegion currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(animationStateTime);

  // draw the texture region (TODO this must probably be changed to not only draw the enemy at (50, 50))
  spriteBatch.begin();
  spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame, 50, 50); // Draw current frame at (50, 50)
  spriteBatch.end();
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I need the array to load all the images into the game